# Default nullptr pointer in class ctor give unresolved external symbol c++

Tags: c++, default, default-constructor

I have the following class (not real names):

```
class CObject1 : public IObject1
{
public:
  CObject1(IObject2 *pIObject2 = nullptr);
}
```

Where the "I" versions are for interface classes.  Now, when I create an instance of CObject1 as:

```
CObject1 object1;
```

I get an unresolved external symbol, complaining about CObject1(void) not being found.  If I try to explicitly declare another ctor as:

```
CObject1()
```

I then obviously get the "multiple default constructors specified" warning, as one would expect.

Why can't the program find my default ctor??

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Additional notes:

- The interface itself does not have a ctor explicitly defined.
- All of this is under the same namespace. I.e. the interface definition, implementation and instantiation.
- I'm seeing this in MS Unit Testing. I don't have a "normal" project I can test this on.

Comment: Well, where *is* the implementation of your constructor? Also, be aware that your definition is for a constructor that takes an argument. The caller is responsible for populating that argument. Is it possible that you have code somewhere that actually expects there to be a default ctor?

Comment: Not able to repro with clang http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f593e56ee403f20, gcc http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/866ce558d29ee66e or msvc http://rextester.com/ODLZ30170

Comment: The implementation is in its cpp file. Really nothing special about it.

Comment: I don't think this would matter, but the interface itself does not explicitly declare a ctor. I figured I'd mention it, in case.

Comment: cannot reproduce https://ideone.com/Bo1yPm

Comment: Hmmm.... I just tested this under an empty console application and it works fines. This seems to point to my MS Unit Test setup.  Either I messed up somewhere... or MS did. If I was a better man, I'd go with me.
Thanks for testing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class does *not* generate a default (`CObject1()`) constructor. What it generates is a constructor that requires one argument, and any code that reads the definition will know to populate that argument if it encounters what would otherwise be a default ctor - which is done at the call site.

```
class C {
public:
  C(int* p = nullptr);
};

C fn() {
  C c{};
  return c;
};
```

[Generates](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang390,options:'-O2+-Wall+-std%3Dc%2B%2B1z',source:'++class+C+%7B%0A++public:%0A++++C(int*+p+%3D+nullptr)%3B%0A++%7D%3B%0A%0A++C+fn()+%7B%0A++++C+c%7B%7D%3B%0A++++return+c%3B%0A++%7D%3B')),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

```
fn():                                 # @fn()
        pushq   %rax
        leaq    (%rsp), %rdi
        xorl    %esi, %esi   ; <<- injects the nullptr
        callq   C::C(int*)   ; <<- note which ctor is called
        popq    %rax
        retq
```

However: the unit testing framework might not be seeing that definition and working with the requirement that your objects have a default ctor. In which case, you should consider writing:

```
CObject1() : CObject1(nullptr) {}
CObject1(IObject2 *pIObject2);
```

Comment: I need to decipher this... but I just pointed out above, in a comment, that when I build an empty console application with that same instantiation... it compiles fine. So your conclusions sound right... I just need to fully understand the reasons now :) Thanks.

Comment: btw kfsone, I DID think about creating 2 explicit constructions and forget about the = nullptr version.  But this is a little disturbing to me, since I do use a few other default values in the ctor's, which means I'd have to modify all of those, just in case. Not too big of a deal, just disturbing cause I really didn't expect that behavior - AT ALL. But I'm no expert.

Comment: Alright... Now that it's not 1AM... I understand your answer. I'm assuming this behavior is not unique to the ctor then.  It concerns me that there are instances where a program might not see functions with default-value parameters and then fail to compile.  (Also... don't know why someone gave a down vote to my question and not explain why.)